# Field Validation error is showing as soon as page loads but should show after Submitting the form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have this in my model:

```
[Required]
public string PasswordLoserFullName { get; set; }
```

And in my  @`using (Html.BeginForm`  I am using it like this:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PasswordLoserFullName, "Name", new { @class = "control-label col-xs-2" })
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PasswordLoserFullName, new { @class = "form-control"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PasswordLoserFullName)
        </div>
    </div>
```

**The problem is as soon as page loads, it is showing the error message.** Well yes the form just loaded, nobody has typed anything. I want it to show when user have clicked the Submit button. Not as soon as the page loads.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does the action method rendering this view look like, and what have you tried?

Comment: See [MVC Razor Validation Errors showing on page load when no data has been posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21296281/mvc-razor-validation-errors-showing-on-page-load-when-no-data-has-been-posted), [Html.ValidationSummary(false, “message”) is always showing, even on page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166997/html-validationsummaryfalse-message-is-always-showing-even-on-page-load), [Validation messages are displayed when page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347827/validation-messages-are-displayed-when-page-load) and so on.

Comment: Do not have a parameter in your GET method which is the model. If you need to pass values to the GET method, use parameters which are `string` etc and then initialize the model with those values in the GET method.

Answer (score 1):

> I want it to show when user have clicked the Submit button. Not as
>   soon as the page loads.

Then, it's a `GET` method which is getting called and for get method don't pass the model at all and just display the page. For `POST` method pass the model and perform validation.

Comment: Hmm OK I see what you are saying. But even on GET part of the action method, for the request password form that is going to load, I still have some fields to show values from model so had to pass model, now I put some dummy value in the field for that one when loading the page but STILL it is showing the error.

Comment: @Bohn, use the `[RequiredValidation]` attribute and set it to `false` since `GET` method doesn't actually require validation.

Comment: hmm, I added this to top of that property, it says can't find such a thing :(   [RequiredValidation = false] , how do you use it ?

Comment: Ok this one worked:  Adding "ModelState.Clear()"  to the GET part.